# javascript - manipulate dropdownlist with another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm new in programming and JavaScript noob so I need you guys help.

I have 2 drop drown list and I am trying to manipulate one drop down list using another drop down list through the help of JavaScript. Both drop down list consists of time in hrs, start time and end time.

The drop down list looks like this

```
<!-- start time -->
<div id="start">
    <p>Start time</p>
    <select name="select1" id="select1" >
        <option value="8:00">8:00</option>
        <option value="8:30">8:30</option>
        <option value="9:00">9:00</option>
        <option value="9:30">9:30</option>
    </select>
</div>

<!--end time -->
<div id="end">
    <p>End time</p>
    <select name="select2" id="select2">
        <option value="8:30">8:30</option>
        <option value="9:00">9:00</option>
        <option value="9:30">9:30</option>
        <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to make sure the end time doesn't start before the start time, and also the start time to end time is a limit of 2 hours. Is there anyway of doing this using JavaScript? no matter how much I search I can't seem to find the solution in the internet.

edit, this is what my actual document looks like.

```
<head>

                    <!-- title -->
    <title> Mycomputer </title>

                    <!-- css link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="second_page.css">

                    <!-- date picker -->
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

    <script>
        $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        minDate: 0, maxDate: 30, showButtonPanel: true});
        });
    </script>






</head>



<body>

    <div id="greybackground">


                    <!-- banner image -->
    <img src="images/banners.jpg" id="banner"/>


                        <!-- buttons -->
    <form action="logout.php">
        <input type="submit" value="logout" class="logout-button"/>
    </form>

    <form action="user.php">
        <input type="submit" value="back" class="back-button"/>
    </form>


                    <!-- headings -->
    <div id="welcome">This is room <?php echo $g; ?></div>

    <div id="box1"></div>

    <div id="intro">1. Choose the computer you would like to book.</div>

    <div id="chooseone">Please choose only one from the following computers:</div>



    <div class="checkbox2">

                    <!-- form -->
        <form action="final_page.php" method="POST">

        <?php

            // to connect to database 
            require("user_connection.php");


            //if statement
            if ($g == C450){


            // checkbox populated with values from database
            $r = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `C450`");
            while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
                echo '<input type="radio" name="bike" 
              value="'.$line['computer_no'].'" checked><label>'.$line['computer_no'].'</label></br>';
            }
            }

        ?>
    </div>



    <div class="checkbox2">

        <?php

            // to connect to database 
            require("user_connection.php");


            //if statement
            if ($g == E300){


            // checkbox populated with values from database
            $s = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `E300`");
            while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($s)) {
                echo '<input type="radio" name="bike" 
                    value="'.$line['computer_no'].'" checked><label>'.$line['computer_no'].'</label></br>';
            }
            }

        ?>

    </div>




    <div class="checkbox2">

        <?php

            // to connect to database 
            require("user_connection.php");


            //if statement
            if ($g == AL10){


            // checkbox populated with values from database
            $s = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `AL10`");
            while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($s)) {
                echo '<input type="radio" name="bike" 
                    value="'.$line['computer_no'].'" checked><label>'.$line['computer_no'].'</label></br>';
            }
            }

        ?>

    </div>




                    <!-- Date -->
    <div id="box2"></div>
    <div id="date">2. Choose a single date you would like to book the room on.</div>

    <div id="groupdate">
    <div id="nametag">Date:</div>
    <div id="dateS"><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"></div>
    </div>




                    <!-- Time -->
    <div id="box3"></div>
    <div id="time">3. Select the preferred start time.</div>

    <div id="grouptime">



            <!-- start time -->

<script>

$('#select1').on('change', function() {
  if($(this).val() > $('#select2').val())
    $('#select2').val($(this).val());
  $('#select2 option').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('value') < $('#select1').val())
      {
        $(this).hide();
        }
    else
      $(this).show();
  });
});


</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


     <div id="start">
        <p>Start time</p>
        <select name="select1" id="select1" >
            <option value="8:00">8:00</option>
            <option value="8:30">8:30</option>
            <option value="9:00">9:00</option>
            <option value="9:30">9:30</option>
            <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
            <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
            <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
            <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
            <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
            <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
            <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
            <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
            <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
            <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
            <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
            <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
            <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
            <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
            <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
            <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
            <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
            <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
            <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
            <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
            <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
            <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
            <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
            <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
        </select>
    </div>


            <!--end time -->
    <div id="end">
        <p>End time</p>
        <select name="select2" id="select2">
            <option value="8:30">8:30</option>
            <option value="9:00">9:00</option>
            <option value="9:30">9:30</option>
            <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
            <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
            <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
            <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
            <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
            <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
            <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
            <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
            <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
            <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
            <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
            <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
            <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
            <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
            <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
            <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
            <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
            <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
            <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
            <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
            <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
            <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
            <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
            <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
            <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
         </select>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div id="box4"></div>
    <div id="review"><p>Please review your booking before saving to make sure there are no </br>accidental error.</p></div>
    <input type="submit" id="save" name="next" Value="save" class="save"/>

    </form>



    <footer>
        <p>Copyright © 2016 MyComputer &nbsp; | &nbsp; Contact information: <a href="mailto:gurungmadan@hotmail.com">gurungmadan@hotmail.com</a></p>
    </footer>


    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Your requirement is not completely clear. What do you mean with "and also the start time to end time is a limit of 2 hours"?

Comment: i meant, if a start time starts at 8:00 then the end time can only have a selection of up to 10:00 or lower.  8:00 +  2hrs = 10:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick snippet, mark the added leading 0 to the value to make the time strings comparable.
You do need to adjust the code a little according to your html code and the desired functionality. You probably should exchange the very simplistic conditions with something more sophisticated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select1').on('change', function() {
      if($(this).val() > $('#select2').val())
        $('#select2').val($(this).val());
      $('#select2 option').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('value') < $('#select1').val())
          {
            $(this).hide();
            }
        else
          $(this).show();
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="start">
        <p>Start time</p>
        <select name="select1" id="select1" >
            <option value="08:00">8:00</option>
            <option value="08:30">8:30</option>
            <option value="09:00">9:00</option>
             <option value="09:30">9:30</option>


        </select>
    </div>


            <!--end time -->
    <div id="end">
        <p>End time</p>
        <select name="select2" id="select2">
            <option value="08:30">8:30</option>
            <option value="09:00">9:00</option>
            <option value="09:30">9:30</option>
            <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
         </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: hi, thankyou for your code, its seems to run well here but when i copy your code and put it in my document and run it in browser its doesn't seem to work? and i have noticed you are using jquery. i have never used jquery before as im a javascript beginner and complete noob but do i have to install some jquery plugin to run this and make it work or somthing?

Comment: Hm, your question is tagged with jQuery so I thought it was an option. The script tag in the html above is all you need to add jQuery library.

Comment: hi, the code you have given me doesn't seem to run on my document for some reason. i have added the actual document above, can you please check to see if i have done anything wrong?

Comment: You should either add the script tag after your html or use a `$(document).ready()` wrapper. The browser needs to have the the elements rendered into the DOM before the Javascript can find them. Right now you are executing the Javascript before the Elements are rendered. I'll edit a ready wrapper into my answer.

Comment: hi, thankyou that helped, however it seems like this only works with the short dropdown list that i provided before but not with my actual document's dropdown list that i provided later. how would i apply this to the long dropdown list on my document?

Comment: You did not change the values of the options to comparable strings (leading 0) But then I would use military time for the value anyways and parse them to Int (parseInt) comparing 830 to 1030 is easy, so is adding 200 for further comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Use the onchange event on select1 and select2 to trigger when the user change the value of them.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Then write a function which checks the values of each select

```
var select1 = document.getElementById("select1").value;
var select2 = document.getElementById("select2").value;
```

You can use regex for example to separe the hours and the minutes in order to compare them: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

You can might want to use Date Object to compare them: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp but this is only an option, in your case I would just compare the hours, then if needed the minutes.

There are many ways to do what you want to do :)

One example using strict Javascript:

```
function check(elt) {
    var select1 = document.getElementById("select1").value;
    var select2 = document.getElementById("select2").value;

    var regex = /([8-9]|10):([03]0)/;
    var match1 = regex.exec(select1);
    var match2 = regex.exec(select2);
    var hours1 = match1[1];
    var hours2 = match2[1];
    if(hours1 >= hours2) {
        var minutes1 = match1[2];
        var minutes2 = match2[2];
        if(minutes1 >= minutes2) {
            // do the changes you want here
            alert("Start time should be before End time!");
        }
    }
    }
```